# What is best system of cooling for my old computer?

Tags: processor, motherboard, cooling

I have done a few of modifications of my oldest computer. It is 17 years old and still working good enough, but I would like to make it less noisy. I don't like how CPU is overheating. Currently, the CPU cooling system doesn't work well. What's best and good for money cooling system?

[image: CPU cooller]

[image: SPEED FUN info]

- I have trying SpeedFun program before I have bought a few fans or coolers.

Result or expectation: I am expecting that it will be less noisy

Comment: It appears that board is a LGA775 socket. I would suggest replacing or fixing that CPU cooler and while you're doing that you should clean all of that dust out of the PC and replace the thermal paste on the CPU. What CPU do you have? Certain models will need stronger coolers than others.

Comment: Not a specific recommendation for a product but I'd second cleaning and replacing the thermal paste, and replacing the fan with one with a modern/good one of the same size

Comment: Clean it and close the side panel. You may also buy a 3pack of be quiet fans since those are more silent from my experience

Answer (score 1):

- blow away the dust with compressed air; if you have an air compressor with a tank at ~100 psi that is optimal versus a little hand held can of compressed.
- verify the cpu cooler fans, and all others, are actually working... by sight or with your finger... your little pic shows 0 rpm.
- for less noise, look for replacement fan for the cpu and for the case especially if those fans when operating are simply noisy... after 17 years fans simply don't run as quiet like when they were new.
- that cooler looks decent, no need to replace it
- remove the cooler off the cpu, clean the mating surfaces, properly apply new cpu thermal grease and a good enough amount and remount the cooler to the cpu; i'd bet doing this would have the biggest impact.
- what you have, is probably *the best cooling system for your old computer*.  Keep it, just clean it up, new fans, new thermal grease.

Comment: To clean the dust, you can also use a vacuum cleaner

Comment: The sucking power of a vacuum is usually a lot weaker than the blowing power from the compressed air cans or a real compressor. Maybe if you have a good vacuum but I would advise using both and have the vacuum ready to suck up the dust cloud.

Comment: Heat conductance can be lost with grit thicker than the paste after it has been squeezed just to fill the micro-scratches. Same with warp or twist.  The coplanarity and less gap is more critical than a little dust between fins.  Then again too many processes and services running with slugware are another cause.  Boot to < 40 processes is my rule of thumb